# Какие есть методы у Object в java?

Tags: java

Базовый класс в Java, как известно, Object. Какие его методы вы можете назвать?

Я нашел такую информацию:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/265373/

Object это базовый класс для всех остальных объектов в Java. Каждый класс наследуется от Object. Соответственно все классы наследуют методы класса Object.

Методы класса Object:

```
public final native Class getClass()
public native int hashCode()
public boolean equals(Object obj)
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
public String toString()
public final native void notify()
public final native void notifyAll()
public final native void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException
public final void wait(long timeout, int nanos) throws InterruptedException
public final void wait() throws InterruptedException
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
```

Можно ли информацию чем-то добавить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы Вы перечислили все. Добавить можно разве что их краткое описание.

1. **protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException** - возвращает shallow (поверхностную) копию объекта. Для использования обязательно д.б. переопределен в классе. Класс должен имплементить маркерный интерфейс Cloneable, иначе метод выкинет CloneNotSupportedException. Типовая реализация:

   ```
   public YourClass clone() { 
       return (YourClass) super.clone(); 
   }
   ```
2. **public boolean equals(Object o)** - возвращает результат сравнения объектов. Текущий объект сравнивается с объектом, который передается в параметр. По умолчанию в Object сравнивает ссылки через == :

   ```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
   ```

   Обязателен для переопределения вместе с hashCode(). Переопределенный метод должен возвращать true, если объекты логически равны.

   Контракт equals:

- рефлексивность: a.equals(a) == true
- симметричность: a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)
- транзитивность: if a.equals(b) == true and b.equals(c) == true -> a.equals(c) == true
- консистентность: повторный вызовов a.equals(b) возвращает тот же результат
- a.equals(null) == false

3. **public int hashCode()** - возвращает хэш объекта. Нужен чтобы с объектом могли работать хэш-таблицы (например, HashMap). Всегда должен предопределяться с equals().

   Контракт hashCode:

- if a.hashCode() вызывается несколько раз, то результат д.б. одинаков
- в определении hashCode() должны участвовать те же поля, что и в equals()
- if a.equals(b) == true -> a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()
- if a.equals(b) == false -> a.hashCode() != b.hashCode() - это не обязательное требование, но желательное т.к. это повышает эффективность хэш-таблиц

4. **public final native Class<?> getClass()** - возвращает runtime class объекта. Инстансы Class репрезентуют любой тип класса или интерфейса а также Enum, массив, аннотацию, примитивы и void. На том, что не является объектом и поэтому не может быть вызван метод getClass() объект Class можно получить с помощью литерала class.
5. **public String toString()** - возвращает строковую презентацию объекта. Реализация в Object:

   ```
    getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
   ```

   Где toHexString() приводит хэш к шестнадцатеричному виду.
6. **public final void wait()** throws InterruptedException - текущий поток переходит из состояния Runnable в состояние ожидания и ожидает до тех пор, пока другой поток не вызовет notify() на этом же lock-объекте. Должен вызываться только в synchronized блоке: synchronized(lock) { lock.wait(); }. В перегруженные методы можно передать максимальное время ожидания. Кроме notify() и истекшего лимита времени ожидание потоком м.б. прервано вызовом interrupt() у ожидающего потока из другого потока.
7. **public final void notify()** - будит поток, который ожидает по монитору lock-объекта, на котором вызван метод. Или 1 из потоков, если ожидающих потоков > 1. Какой именно - мы предсказать не можем. Должен вызываться только в synchronized блоке.
8. **public final void notifyAll()** - будит все потоки, синхронизированные по объекту у которого вызван метод
9. **protected void finalize() throws Throwable** - вызывается, когда больше нет причин для того, чтобы объект был доступен из любого живого потока.

- Вызывается за время существования объекта в памяти только 1 раз.
- В Object не делает ничего (у метода пустое тело).
- В наследуемых классах может быть переопределен, если есть какие-то операции, которые должны быть обязательно выполнены перед уничтожением объекта.
- Метод может сделать объект снова доступным, повесив ссылку на this.
- Использовать явный вызов этого метода - очень плохая практика.
- Переопределять также не нужно практически никогда. Разве что как средство последнего шанса на высвобождение системных ресурсов. Но именно как последнего. Шатно это должно делаться при помощи конструкции try-with-resources.
- Если все-таки нужно переопределить, то надо не забыть в конце метода вызвать super.finalize () в блоке finally.
- В HotSpot VM GC не вызывает finalize() напрямую, а только добавляет объекты в специальный список, вызывая статический метод Finalizer.register(Object). В список добавляются только объекты с переопределенным finalize(). Объект Finalizer представляет собой ссылку на объект, для которого надо вызвать finalize(), и хранит ссылки на следующий и предыдущий Finalizer, формируя двусвязный список. Вызов finalize() происходит в отдельном потоке Finalizer, кот. создается при запуске VM. Исключения, брошенные в finalize(), не обрабатываются потоком-финализатором, т.е. данный стектрейс скорее всего нельзя будет отследить.
- В Java 9 deprecated.
- в качестве альтернативы переопределения finalize() можно использовать фантомную ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [документации Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) – нет.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик!