# В HashMap встречаются одинаковые ключи! Почему?

Tags: java, spring-boot, map, key, hashmap

У меня имеется цикл, который наполняет `HashMap`. Работает по принципу - для каждого руководителя отдела(например: бухгалтерия) имеется значение в виде списка работников этого отдела. То есть: Руководитель - ключ, список его подчиненных - список. Как так получается, что при выполнении цикла у меня получется несколько одинаковых ключей. Я на всех ресурсах вычитываю, что Мап хранит УНИКАЛЬНЫЕ ключи, либо их перезаписывает за место уже имеющихся. Как это можно исправить(возможно,есть варианты удаление всех дубликатов ключей)? И как так вообще происходит?

P.S. В классе самом equals и hashCode перепоределены. Так же в класса Gate, Depatrment и Room.

Employee:

```java
public class Employee extends EmployeeGeneral {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee)) return false;
        Employee that = (Employee) o;
        return room.equals(that.room) && department.equals(that.department) && upDepartment.equals(that.upDepartment) && gate.equals(that.gate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(room, department, upDepartment, gate);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 372342343809L;

    private Room room;

    private Department department;

    private Department upDepartment;

    private Gate gate;

    public static final Field ROOM;
```

Метод:

```java
for (MSEmployee m : employees) {

            MSEmployee manager = msEmployeeRepository
                    .findFirstByDocID(departmentManagerMap.get(m.getDepartment().getId()));

            if (manager == null) continue;

            List<MSEmployee> msEmployeeList = msEmployeeRepository
                    .findAllByIdInAndDepartmentDocIdIn(employeesIds, manager.getDepartmentDocId());

            employeesWithManagers.put(manager, msEmployeeList);
        }
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118830/discussion-on-question-by-artur-vartanyan--hashmap---).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для переопределения hadhCode желательно использовать финальные поля: хешмапа работает примерно след образом: у объекта берется хеш-код, по этому хеш коду обычно определяется, на каком индексе располагается объект в ассоциативном массиве (в нашел случае хеш мап).например: hashmap у нас размером 16, а хешкод у объекта 31, значит этот объект поместится на позицию 31%16=15 (индекс). Тоесть, чтобы достать значение из мапы мы просто обращаемся к индексу, как в обычном массиве, поэтому использование hashset hashmap такое быстрое. Когда происходят коллизии (тоесть хешкоды совпадают у разных объектов), в этой мапе эти объекты помещаются на один индекс, но в односвязный список. И когда мы хотим достать объект по индексу, мы видим: тут у нас односвязный список, значит нам придется найти нужный нам объект с помощью линейного поиска - здесь и вступает в дело переопределенный equals(). Если вы работаете в intellij, нажмите комбинацию клавиш alt+insert(виндовс) , и в меню появится генератор, в списке которого вам нужно выбрать equals + hashcode, - тогда среда разработки все сделает за вас. Я бы предложила использовать в переопределении этих методов, например, id работника - private final поле, и тогда понадобится только оно, при условии, что для каждого работника айдишник уникален

Comment: имхо, подробности реализации hashmap тут лишние (и не полные), так как реализации могут быть разные. А вот чего не хватает, так это требований к equals и hashcode функциям.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас одинаковые хешкоды Employee, то исходя из показанного кода логически вытекает только 2 варианта:

1. У Вас не переопределены hashCode() в классах Room, Department и Gate + вы в разные экземпляры employee передаете одни и те же экземпляры этих классов, которые сравниваются по == в непереопределенных hashCode().
2. У Вас неправильно переопределены hashCode() в перечисленных классах. Если 2 сущности находятся в разном состоянии, то согласно контракту hashCode очень желательно, чтобы у них были разные хеш суммы. Что это за контракт можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1236146/258227).

PS Зачем Вы добавили в hashCode() и equals() public static final поле? Оно не участвует в состоянии employee. Это константа, которая одинакова для всех экземпляров employee.